# How to install pymedia without compiling prereq's from source?

Tags: sound, mp3, build

I'm trying to install pymedia: http://pymedia.org/ on ubuntu.  I'm fine with building pymedia itself from source, as that seems my only option, but I'd rather not have source built versions of its prerequisites lying around if I can avoid it.

I installed most of the prereq's with the following:

`sudo apt-get install python-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libfaad-dev libasound2-dev libmp3lame-dev`

Then I downloaded the pymedia source tarball and ran:

`python setup.py build`

With that I get:

```
OGG          : found
VORBIS       : found
FAAD         : found
MP3LAME      : found
VORBISENC    : found
ALSA         : found
Continue building pymedia ? [Y,n]:
```

Which looks good.  I hit yes.. and it errors out with:

```
#...
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/sound/sound.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/sound/resample.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/sound/fft.o -logg -lvorbis -lfaad -lmp3lame -lvorbisenc -lasound -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/pymedia/audio/sound.so
/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/sound/sound.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/sound/sound.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

This error is not related to the prereqs, it's likely a bad build script.

If I understand this correct (my C-foo is weak) 64bits shared libraries must be compiled with the -fPIC flag and sound.cpp isn't in this case.

In the setup.py of pymedia there is a function called *disable_fPIC* that forces gcc to compile all it's libraries without it. You can try to disable that function (just replace all the code with a pass statement) and try to compile it again. It shoul read something like this:

```
def disable_fPIC():
    pass
```

I can't test it as my machine is 32bits, so I can just hope that it helps.